# displaying fusion charts and widgets

Tags: tomcat, flex4, fusioncharts

I have a project which has fusion widgets embedded in it. wen i run the application directly in flash builder it displays the fusion widgets but when i run it in tomcat server it doesnt display the widgets.

what do i need to configure to run it in tomcat server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please let me know if you have placed all the chart/widgets swf files in the deployed location?

Also please let me know if the application that you are running directly from the tomcat server is also a Flex application.

If it is a separate HTML based application you would need to use chart/gauges swf flies from core FusionCharts v3.2/FusionWidgets v3.1 pack.

Answer (score 1):

it is working fine now. i had not placed swf files in deploy location.